# Interpretation of Volatility of Volatility (VVIX)

Tags: volatility, vix

Recently I came across the VVIX index (also known as VIX of VIX), which represents the 30 day implied (expected) Volatility of the VIX Index. I studied CBOE's Whitepaper for the VIX, which explains the methodology used for calculating the VIX and VVIX. While I think to have understood the calculations for the two indices, I am still struggling to interpret volatility of volatility itself. Doing research online I found the following two explanations:

$Explanation\; 1$:
"If we drop statistical rigour for a moment, you can think of volatility (roughly) as the possible range of a price change for a day, and then vol of vol is how much those ranges change from day to day...In this sense, the indicators are suggesting that while the market expects price changes to be relatively small, it thinks there is a larger than usual possibility that the magnitude of those price changes will change as well (and from experience, likely become larger)."

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/6mf8ps/can_anyone_explain_vvix/

$Explanation\; 2$
"Many refer to VVIX as a “volatility of volatility” measure or a 2nd derivative of the SPX. If the VIX is the speed of the SPX, VVIX is the acceleration of the SPX...It measures the quickness of market moves. If the VVIX is low, declines and rallies in the market are slower and take months to develop. If the VVIX is high, declines and rallies in the market are faster and take only days or weeks to develop. The higher the VVIX, the sharper the EKG diagram of the market. While the VIX measures the amplitude of SPX oscillations, the VVIX measures their period."

Source: https://www.investing.com/analysis/record-vvix-suggests-market-turbulence-will-remain-200529555

So now finally my question: First of all are these explanations roughly accurate? And if so, how can the two explanations be put together? Both seem to make sense for me, but I don't see where they come together.

Thanks in advance and cheers, Sanoj

Comment: The second description is poetry rather than a technical statement. In particular where it refers to speed and acceleration or to amplitude and period. These are concepts from other fields that are only loose analogies at best (and that contradict each othr). The first explanation is closer to the truth IMO. The vol of SPX changes and this instability of vol can itself be measured.